# Converting content of text area into an array

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have a form with a  text area in html.
I want to get the content of this text area in php so that each line can be stored in an array. I tried using implode with'/n'. but its not working. how can i do that.

Here is my code

```
$notes = explode('/n',$_POST['notes']);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
$notes = explode("\n", $_POST['notes']);
```

(Back slash, not forward slash, and double quotes instead of single quotes)

Answer (score 7):

Palantir's solution will work only if the lines ends with \n (Linux default line ending).

Eg.

```
$text     = "A\r\nB\r\nC\nD\rE\r\nF";    
$splitted = explode( "\n", $text );

var_dump( $splitted );
```

will output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "A "
  [1]=>
  string(2) "B "
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "D E "
  [4]=>
  string(1) "F"
}
```

If not, you should use this:

```
$text     = "A\r\nB\r\nC\nD\rE\r\nF";
$splitted = preg_split( '/\r\n|\r|\n/', $text );
var_dump( $splitted );
```

Or this:

```
$text     = "A\r\nB\r\nC\nD\rE\r\nF";
$text     = str_replace( "\r", "\n", str_replace( "\r\n", "\n", $text ) );
$splitted = explode( "\n", $text );
var_dump( $splitted );
```

I think the last one will be faster because it does not use regular expressions.

Eg.

```
$notes = str_replace(
    "\r",
    "\n",
    str_replace( "\r\n", "\n", $_POST[ 'notes' ] )
);

$notes = explode( "\n", $notes );
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `PHP_EOL` for textarea of form to array, use it:

```
array_values(array_filter(explode("\n", str_replace("\r", '', $_POST['data']))))
```